# Can Gatekeeper be disabled via terminal in OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, terminal, security, gatekeeper

How can you disable Gatekeeper via Terminal Commands in OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion? I am looking to replicate the Security & Privacy preference pane selection to allow applications downloaded from **Anywhere** to run:

[image]

By having a terminal command, I can write a script to do this task remotely rather than manually going to each Mac and changing these settings with a mouse and several clicks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [spctl](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/spctl.8.html) tool should do the job.

`sudo spctl --master-disable` will turn off the Gatekeeper checks, and `sudo spctl --master-enable` will re-enable them (to the default setting of App Store and signed apps — it doesn't appear that setting it to App Store-only is possible).

Note that it will not throw any error if you run it without `sudo` permissions, but `sudo` is in fact required.

Comment: The man page says that
spctl --disable --label "Mac App Store"
Will disable installation of all Mac App Store Apps, so it would seem possible that it could --enable only M.A.S. apps.

Comment: @SamuelWalker I didn't notice that before, but what would really be required is a rule or label that's equivalent to all non-App Store apps. Otherwise it's moot, as you can't disable all other sources independently from what I can tell.

Comment: That's true. I've just looked in the actual SystemPolicy Database, and from what I can tell there's only a few labels that it uses. "GKE","Developer ID", "Mac App Store", "Apple System", "Apple Installer", "No Matching Rule". Although as these Strings are arbitrary [And may change in future OSX versions] this may be too hacky, but it seems possible that you could manually disable GKE and Developer ID.

Comment: @robmathers, thanks for your response! I learned another work-around: you can right click the installer and click open (which will open the app w/o checking w/ gatekeeper)

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely the easier way if you just need to run some something on a one-off basis.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

See [the man page for spctl](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/spctl.8.html)

Answer (score 3):

Either of these also disables the Gatekeeper dialogs (after restarting), but they don't change the setting shown in System Preferences.

```
sudo defaults write /var/db/SystemPolicy-prefs.plist enabled -string no
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool false
```

I don't know if `spctl --master-disable` is somehow different from disabling Gatekeeper from System Preferences, but `spctl --status` changes to `assessments disabled` after disabling Gatekeeper in System Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:

- To disable Gatekeeper, use the command `sudo spctl --global-disable`.
- To re-enable Gatekeeper, use the command `sudo spctl --global-enable`.

The command `spctl --master-disable` is no longer supported. This change was introduced in MacOS v10.15.7 (last version of Catalina).