# A security update locked OSX.GenieoDropper.A

Tags: macos, security, malware

I need to launch an app but OSX recognise it as a malware.

While launching this app, OSX says "app will damage this computer. You should eject this disk image. It contain OSX.GenieoDropper.A".

Normally, to bypass this alert, the method was to right-click the icon and select open when pushing alt, but neither this seems working, so how can I bypass this alert?

Comment: How certain are you that it's a false positive?

Comment: I have old "similar app" which I've already used correctly and now are locked too, so seems Apple decided to lock all the category.

Comment: And app is locked because of OSX.GenieoDropper.A , which is a common component of a "particular kind of apps" which, compressively, Apple should hate...

Comment: Which applications are being blocked by this?

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan mainly hacks and keygens.

Comment: Given that keygens are notorious for being infected with malware are you certain this is a false positive by Apple? Have you tried scanning it with another tool that checks for malware? Or submitting to http://virustotal.com to get a consensus opinion?

Comment: I didn't knew about virustotal.com; I tried it and it gave me a 0/53, so my file should be clean and this issue is all only about Apple, right?

Answer (score 1):

Sorted: type in the terminal

`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine`

leave a space after "quarantine" and then drag & drop the .app file.

Then press Return...et voila'!

The `-cr` flag is for operating systems before (and including) Mavericks. For newer operating systems (Yosemite & El Capitan) you must specify the flag `-d` along with the attribute (`com.apple.quarantine`) you wish to remove.

Comment: Open Terminal and Run: **xattr -d com.apple.quarantine {Your App Path}** Works like a charm. OSX 10.11.3

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to contend with Gatekeeper, XProtect and SIP to get around the protection with which OS X is confronting you.

1. Right click and open in finder just white lists an app in [Gatekeeper](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75390/can-gatekeeper-be-disabled-via-terminal-in-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion) - in this case, you tried that and we can rule that out.
2. [Xprotect](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80590/how-can-i-circumvent-xprotect-and-re-enable-java-applets) is the name of the file Apple updates to black list known bad software and insecure versions of plug-in like flash, [java](https://managingosx.wordpress.com/2013/01/31/disabled-java-plugins-xprotect-updater/) and so forth.
3. If you find you cannot edit the XProtect files (even as root or using `sudo`) - you'll need to [disable SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11).

I would discourage you from disabling all three of these protections and instead rip out the offending libraries from the app in question or get it updated from the vendor/source.

That being said - have at learning and removing the protections one by one and maybe check your backups if you aren't doing this on a throw-away OS or virtual machine that you know won't cause you to lose actual work or personal data to the likely malware.

Comment: In XProtect I've found a "com.genie.safari", but it's an Extension. Do you think that removing this item from extensions array will solve my issue?

Answer (score -1):

running

> xattr -cr

will do the job

this will remove the extended file attributes (for each file from .app) and allow it to run

apple doc set for xattr:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xattr.1.html

Answer (score -3):

run `xattr -cr <your.app>`

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: "option -c not recognized"